# app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php, where can I find this in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

where can I find this file in Magento 2?

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out it in below path

```
vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php
```

Comment: Hi,

I have added an module and requested with URL. Google automatically adding a trailing slash. Can you help me how to resolve this in magento 2?

Whether to remove this or to make it work in magento 2?

Comment: got it, thank you for finding path in magento2

Answer (score 0):

It can be one of following.

```
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/AbstractBlock.php
vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/AbstractBlock.php
vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php
```

Comment: Hi all,

I have added an module and requested with URL. Google automatically adding a trailing slash. Can anyone help me how to resolve this in magento 2?

Whether to remove this or to make it work in magento 2?

Comment: how to override defaultmode.php in magento 2.2.3 for captcha modification?